# Qt: Opening a file in one thread, writing data to a file in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, asynchronous, qthread

In my implementation, I create a class that allows you to write data to a file asynchronously, (this means that data is sent to a temporary buffer when writing, and another thread reads this buffer and writes all the received data to the file synchronously).

And then the question arises.

I know that threads share a common memory area, but isn't it a mistake to `create` and `open` a file in one thread and write data in another ? If this is not a problem, then the following example is absolutely valid and has no errors in it. (Details are omitted in the example, only the main idea is demonstrated).

*P.S* **It is worth noting that it is important for me to open the file in one thread, where the file is created, since in case of an error opening the file, I want to immediately return the error, and not wait for the thread to start, attempt to open the file in the created thread and only after that, realizing that the file cannot be opened, stop the thread and output the error.**

```cpp
class AsyncFileWriter final : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

    QFile*              p_file;
    mutable QMutex      m_mutex;
    QVector<QByteArray> m_tempBuffer;
    QWaitCondition      m_waitCondition;
    std::atomic_bool    m_stopRequested;

public:

    void stop() noexcept
    {
        if (isRunning()) {
            m_stopRequested.store(true);
            QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
            m_waitCondition.wakeOne();
        }
    }

    bool start(const QString& aFileName) noexcept
    {
        if (isRunning()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (aFileName.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        p_file = new QFile(aFileName);
        if (!p_file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            delete p_file;
            p_file = nullptr;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // void wait() noexcept;
    void write(const QByteArray& aData) noexcept
    {
        if (!aData.isEmpty()) {
            QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
            m_tempBuffer.push_back(aData);
            m_waitCondition.wakeOne();
        }
    }

    explicit AsyncFileWriter(QObject* aParrent) :
        QThread(aParrent),
        p_file(nullptr),
        m_mutex(),
        m_tempBuffer(),
        m_waitCondition(),
        m_stopRequested(false)
    {}

    AsyncFileWriter& operator=(const AsyncFileWriter&) = delete;
    AsyncFileWriter& operator=(AsyncFileWriter&&)      = delete;
    AsyncFileWriter(const AsyncFileWriter&)            = delete;
    AsyncFileWriter(AsyncFileWriter&&)                 = delete;
    
    virtual ~AsyncFileWriter() override
    {
        if (isRunning()) {
            stop();
            (void) wait(UINT64_MAX);
        }
    }

private:

    void run() noexcept override
    {
        auto writeAllData = [&]() -> void {
            QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
            if (!m_tempBuffer.isEmpty()) {
                const QVector<QByteArray> buffer(std::move(m_tempBuffer));
                locker.unlock();
                for (const auto& dataFragment : buffer) {
                    const qint64 written = p_file->write(dataFragment);
                    if (written != dataFragment.size()) {
                        return p_file->error();
                    }
                }
                if (!p_file->flush()) {
                    return p_file->error();
                }
                return QFileDevice::FileError::NoError;
            }
        };
        
        while (true) {
            m_mutex.lock();
            (void) m_waitCondition.wait(&m_mutex);
            m_mutex.unlock();
            if (writeAllData() != QFileDevice::FileError::NoError) {
                break;
            }
            if (m_stopRequested.load()) {
                m_stopRequested.store(false);
                (void) writeAllData();
                break;
            }
        }
        p_file->close();
        delete p_file;
        p_file = nullptr;
        m_mutex.lock();
        m_tempBuffer.clear();
        m_mutex.unlock();
    }

};
```

Comment: I think in your PS you mixed up "stream" and "thread"

Comment: I agree with you, I made a mistake. I mean about opening a file in one thread, and writing and closing in another.

Comment: you can still [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75210013/edit) the quesiton

Comment: If you create and open the file before starting the thread, and then access that file (read/write/close) only from the thread, then I think it should be fine. AFAIR starting the thread (and also joining) creates an implicit synchronization point, so this won't be a data race.

Comment: The data is written to a file and closed only in a separate thread. The client cannot close or write data to a file in its thread, this is important to note.

Comment: I am sure there can be no race in such an implementation, the only question here is whether it is right to create your own "void start(fileName)" function and open the file inside this function and, if successful, start the thread.